How to use redis `monitor` to pull historical commands issued to Redis?
Is there a way to get the historical commands issued to redis using the monitor command? This seems to only stream the commands issue from that point onwards.
I tried using redis-cli monitor but this doesn't show historical commands, instead it shows the commands from that point on.
